# Best linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

I have a matrix $A_{n\times m_1}$ and $B_{n\times m_2}$
where $n < m_1 \text{ and } n < m_2$
I need to find $T$ such that $\underset{T}{argmin} ||A T - B||$.

If $n > m_1 \text{ and } n > m_2$, then it is easy:
$A T = B \rightarrow  (A^T A)^{-1}A^T A T =(A^T A) A^T B \underset{(A^T A)^{-1}A^T A = I}{\rightarrow
} T = (A^T A) A^T B$

but if $n < m_1 $, then $(A^T A)^{-1}$ does not exist.

how can I solve my problem?

Comment: Take $T = A^+B$, where $A^+$ denotes the [MP pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse).

Comment: Hi Ben.
The  $A^+$ does not exist.
Since $A^T A $ is singular

Comment: The matrix $A^+$ exists regardless of whether $A^TA$ is singular